# Match String But Don't Match Specific Pattern If It's There In Python

Tags: python, regex, svn

I'm trying to match a string all the way to the end, but if there is another string separated by a space, then I just want to match the first string and not this extra pattern.  This extra patter always starts with:

```
(from
```

Here's an example of a set of strings:

```
M /trunk
M /trunk/src/chip/GCC/ARMCMx/STM32F4xx/vectors.c
A /trunk/src/hal/include/spdif.h (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/include/spdif.h:1078)
M /trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SAI/sai_lld.h
A /trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SPDIF (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SPDIF:1078)
A /trunk/src/hal/src/spdif.c (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/src/spdif.c:1078)
```

So as you can see, a few of those lines have an extra string after the initial path is displayed.  Showing which branch my code commits came from.  I only want the beginning portion of the string, all the way to the end of the path.  I don't want the section where it shows which branch it came from.  How would I go about doing this?

I thought this would work:

```
(.+)[\s]
```

But it matches the entire line and I don't know why.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about a simple `(?m)^(?:(?!\s*\().)+`

Comment: @sln: The lookahead is *far too expensive* and not needed here, compare [**yours**](https://regex101.com/r/cBAOPA/2/) with [**mine**](https://regex101.com/r/cBAOPA/1/) and see that yours needs 10 times more steps to reach the same result.

Comment: @Jan - right you are !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you could use

```
^[A-Z]+\s+(\S+)
```

... and take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cBAOPA/1/).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

string = """
M /trunk
M /trunk/src/chip/GCC/ARMCMx/STM32F4xx/vectors.c
A /trunk/src/hal/include/spdif.h (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/include/spdif.h:1078)
M /trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SAI/sai_lld.h
A /trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SPDIF (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SPDIF:1078)
A /trunk/src/hal/src/spdif.c (from /branches/spdif_446/src/hal/src/spdif.c:1078)
"""

rx = re.compile(r'^[A-Z]+\s+(\S+)', re.MULTILINE)
files = rx.findall(string)
print(files)

# ['/trunk', '/trunk/src/chip/GCC/ARMCMx/STM32F4xx/vectors.c', 
#  '/trunk/src/hal/include/spdif.h', '/trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SAI/sai_lld.h', 
#  '/trunk/src/hal/platforms/STM32/SPDIF', '/trunk/src/hal/src/spdif.c']
```

---

Finally, to answer your initial question, the pattern `(.+)[\s]` matches any character (`.`, except newlines) at least once, but possibly more up to the end of the line. This is followed by a (in this case needless) character class (`[...]`) including whitespaces (`\s`). So, n the end, it matches every line including newlines - which is the same as not using a regular expression at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match before a possible `(` it's

`(?m)^[^(\r\n]+`